# Filter chars that have more than 2bytes

Tags: php, character-encoding

I need to filter chars that have more than 2 bytes. So

"test öüß ()?" should go through, "☑" and emojis should be filtered. I tried quite some different ways (utf8_decode, the mb_convert functions) but I'm unable to get it working properly. It always also removes 2 bytes chars like "ö".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$str = 'abc★def';
mb_substitute_character('none');  // Set mb_convert_encoding() to strip invalid characters
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ascii', 'utf-8'); // convert utf-8 to ascii, stripping invalid characters
var_dump($str);  // now contains 'abcdef'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also filters 2-byte characters like the german umlauts "ö", "ü", etc

Comment: @Michael Due to a quirk of PHP that is correct.  Use encoding `8bit` if you wish to leave ASCII characters above 127 intact.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your last comment. Where should i use 8bit encoding? THanks

Comment: Just to point that out, let's say the input is "abc★def_-öü", I want the ouput to be "abcdef_-öü"

Comment: @Michael Use encoding '8bit' instead of 'ascii' if you want to prevent ASCII characters above 127 from being stripped.